# Generate a weekly program using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a script that displays the program of all employees for the current week.
In order to take the program for the current week I use:

```
SELECT * FROM program
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY employee ASC
```

The script generates a HTML table using PHP, this is the structure of the table:

```
===============================================================
| Employee | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
===============================================================
```

The admin selects the date in which the employee will do an action and it will be inserted into the MySQL database.

This is what I want to get:

```
===============================================================
| Employee | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
===============================================================
| John     | Deliver|         | Deliver   |          |        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Steve    |        | Deliver | Deliver   |          | Deliver|
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make the script detect the day of the week in which the employee will take the action from the database? The employee can work everyday or only few days a week, so I need to display a blank `<td>` where it's nothing to do for that person.

The MySQL fields are `id`, `employee`, `date` and `action`.

I can post what I did 'till now, but it's a simple `while` that inserts only the name, because I have no idea about how I can do the rest. I need an idea.

Here is a sample of my code, as requested:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM program WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) ORDER BY employee ASC");
    echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
                            <th>Employee</th>
                            <th>Monday</th>
                            <th>Tuesday</th>
                            <th>Wednesday</th>
                            <th>Thursday</th>
                            <th>Friday</th>
                            </tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td> $row[employee] </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

The table from the database has a `date` field, in which the admin selects the date through a `<form>`, I've done that part.

Comment: Provide sample data that generates the given output.

Comment: What information is there in the database? How do you know that John on Monday did a 'Deliver'? Does this come from the db, or goes into it? Please provide more information in this area.

Comment: As you requested, I've edited the post and added more information. 
@Iuqita the administrator works through a `<form>` and selects the employee's name from another table from this database, the date is selected using `<input type="date" />` and selects the action from another table containing the possible actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but a note that a blank td will cause you problems in HTML tables, so be sure to put a non-breaking space in any blank td, using

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have built-in support for the sort of crosstab query you are looking to do. You could put together an ugly query with a bunch of CASE statements to return your data in a crosstab format like you desire, but since this can trivially be done in heh application logic, this might not be the best approach.  My suggestion would be to query like this:

```
SELECT employee, WEEKDAY(date) as day_index
FROM program
WHERE
date BETWEEN
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(),0), ' Sunday', '%X%V %W') AND
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(),0), ' Saturday', '%X%V %W')
ORDER BY employee ASC, day_index ASC
```

You may be asking why Such a weird WHERE clause.  Well it is so you can take advantage of having an index on date such that the query can be optimized.  Your current approach does not allow for an index to be used as you are comparing two computed values.  It also doesn't take the year into account (only the week of the year) which would cause problem if you have data in the table for more than one year.

You could just as easily calculate the date range in PHP and change the where clause to:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

This would give results like:

```
TED | 0  <--- Sunday
TED | 2  <--- Tuesday
BILL | 1 <--- Monday
```

You could then build a multidimensional array with the result set:

```
$table = array();
while $row = (/* your MySQL row retrieval method here */)
    $table[$row['employee']][] = $row['day_index'];
}
```

This makes it easy to output your table like:

```
// not shown: output table header before this loop

foreach($table as $employee => $days) {
    echo '<tr><td>'. $employee . '</td>';
    for ($i = 0; $i++; $i < 7) { // you could use ($i = 1; $i++; $ < 6) if you want only weekdays in output
        if (in_array((string)$i, $days)) {
            echo '<td>Delivery</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```